# How to parse String to java.util.Date in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

This is my form in time and out time details inTimeFirst, outTimeFirst, inTimeSecond, outTimeShift are of time data type in database and total hours is double(10,2) type. But in entity class it is of Date type.
Here is my form

```
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{attendanceController.attendanceApp.attendance.empId}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{employeeController.empapp.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" var="comp" itemLabel="#{comp.empNumber}" itemValue="#{comp.empId}" />
                <f:converter converterId="employeeconvert" /> 
            </p:selectOneMenu>       
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="Mark Attendance">
          <h:outputLabel value="Attendance:" for="attendance" />   
          <h:selectOneMenu id="attendance" valueChangeListener="#{attendanceController.attendanceApp.valuChangeHandler}" onchange="submit()" immediate="true">
        <f:selectItem itemValue=" " itemLabel="--select--" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="P" itemLabel="P"/>
         <f:selectItem itemValue="L" itemLabel="L"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="HL" itemLabel="HL"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>  
          <h:outputLabel value="Leave Type:" for="attendance" />    
      <h:selectOneMenu disabled="#{!attendanceController.attendanceApp.visible}" value="#{attendanceController.attendanceApp.attendance.leaveId}">
       <f:selectItems value="#{leavecont.leaveapp.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" var="leav" itemLabel="#{leav.leaveName}" itemValue="#{leav.leaveId}"/>
       <f:converter converterId="leavesconverter" />
   </h:selectOneMenu>
      </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="In Time">

          <p:inputText value="#{attendanceController.attendanceApp.attendance.inTimeFirst}" size="5" maxlength="5"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="Out Time">

          <p:inputText value="#{attendanceController.attendanceApp.attendance.outTimeFirst}" size="5" maxlength="5"/>
      </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="In Time">

          <p:inputText value="#{attendanceController.attendanceApp.attendance.inTimeSecond}" size="5" maxlength="5"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column headerText="Out Time">

          <p:inputText value="#{attendanceController.attendanceApp.attendance.outTimeShift}" size="5" maxlength="5"/>
      </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Total Hours">

          <p:inputText value="#{attendanceController.attendanceApp.attendance.totalHours}" size="5" maxlength="5">
              <h:commandButton value="Calculate"  action="#{attendanceController.attendanceApp.calculateTotalHours()}" style="font: 15px"  />
          </p:inputText>
      </p:column>
        </p:dataTable
```

Here is the method i am calling from command button with name calculate when i enter intime,outtime and press calculate button i should get total hours here is my calculate method which i am calling

```
public String calculateTotalHours(){
   long firstShiftseconds = attendance.getOutTimeFirst().getTime()-attendance.getInTimeFirst().getTime();
     long secondShiftseconds = attendance.getOutTimeShift().getTime()-attendance.getInTimeSecond().getTime();
  double totalhours=(double)(firstShiftseconds+secondShiftseconds)/1000*60*60;
  JSFUtil.addSuccessMessage(" "+totalhours);
  attendance.setTotalHours(totalhours);
 return "Employee_attendance";
}
```

Cannot convert 9:00 of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date error is arrising

Comment: You can remove the "jsf" and "primefaces" tags for this question bro!

Comment: Looks like a better title for your question would be `How to parse String to java.util.Date in JSF?`. And you should whittle down your question and example code to the absolute minimum needed to demonstrate the problem.